# Optimising structure of exp_channel_data table

Tags: database, mysql, channel-fields, index

I have a site with around 800 columns on exp_channel_data table. I would like to know if I can go ahead and optimise the structure of this table by doing the following 
1) changing field from text to a suitable smaller data type like varchar 
2) alter indexes

If I go ahead and do these changes will expression engine override these changes next time I try to save to dB or save site settings or any such thing.

Answer (score 0):

Errr... when you've reached that many columns (therefore, that many fields in field groups, around 400 fields), you probably want to think of a higher-level refactor process. This will be much more fool-proof than manually editing database column types.

Sure, the example you gave will give you more space with your total amount of available columns and your database imprint. But that isn't addressing the issue and will likely come back to bite you in the behind. It's also highly manual and will require your intervention in customizing all of those columns.

EE won't reformat your column types after they are created (after making a new field). So you have no real issue there. You might find EE tries to save something to a modified field it can't handle, resulting in a MySQL error.

You should really look at the systemic problem: you have way too many custom fields in one site.

Can you describe the situation of this site that is resulting in so many custom fields? We can probably help you better with more information as to how this site reached so many fields.